# How to integrate $\int (x^{6}+x^{9})^{\frac{1}{6}}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to evaluate $$\int (x^{6}+x^{9})^{\frac{1}{6}}dx?$$

I am trying to evaluate this integral by taking out a common factor of $x^{6}$. Now the integral is  $$\int x(1+x^{3})^{\frac{1}{6}}dx.$$

Now I am thinking of writing $x=\frac{x^{2}}{x}$. So, the above integral is becoming $$\int \frac{x^{2}(1+x^{3})^{\frac{1}{6}}}{x}dx$$. Now I substituted $x^{3}=u$. So, $x^{2}dx=\frac{1}{3}du$.

Therefore, the integral will be $$\frac{1}{3}\int\frac{(1+u)^{\frac{1}{6}}}{u^{\frac{1}{3}}}du.$$

Now, I am thinking of substituting $u=tan^{3}\theta$. So, $du=3(tan^{2}\theta)(sec^{2}\theta)d\theta$. So, the above integral will be $$\int (1+tan^{3}\theta)^{\frac{1}{6}}(tan\theta)(sec^{2}\theta)d\theta.$$ But after this step I can't proceed further. Please help me out.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BPower%5B%5C%2840%29Power%5Bx%2C6%5D%2BPower%5Bx%2C9%5D%5C%2841%29%2CDivide%5B1%2C6%5D%5D%2Cx%5D

Comment: Please show me the full solution.

Comment: Can you tell me the sources from which you take these integrals?

Comment: Pro tip: type an integral into Wolfram Alpha. If it cannot do it, or (like here) it spews something strange looking (here a hypergeometric function), the indefinite integral (usually) cannot be written in terms of elementary functions at all. Meaning that either somebody is pulling your leg, or you are supposed to do something else with it. Caveat: There are people who think of hypergeometric functions as elementary. If you need to ask, you are not among them :-)

Comment: why this question has $3$ downvotes ???

Comment: Not sure why this is getting downvoted, the person asking has presented what they are asking clearly and showed what they have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot avoid hypergeometric function or the binomial expansion.

Making the problem more general
$$I=\int \left(x^n+x^{3 n/2}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\,dx=\frac{2 }{5}x^{5/2} \,
   _2F_1\left(-\frac{5}{n},-\frac{1}{n};\frac{n-5}{n};-x^{-n/2}
   \right)$$ which is
$$\frac{2\,x^{5/2}}{\Gamma \left(-\frac{1}{n}\right) }\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}\,\frac{ \Gamma \left(k-\frac{1}{n}\right)}{(k
   n-5)\, \Gamma (k+1)}\,\,x^{-\frac{k n}{2}}$$